# primary key is not added as reference to foreign key in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I want to add a foreign key to my **schools** table but the primary key of the **provinces** table is not added to the foreign key reference.

This is my Schools Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string("name");
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger("province_id");
    });
}
```

and Provinces Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('provinces', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string("name",255);
    });
}
```

and this is my Foreign key constraint

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('province_id')->reference('id')->on('provinces');
    });
}
```

and this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJJaV.jpg)
If there is a solution tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and also check the sequence of your migrations.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('student_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string("name",64);
        $table->string("father_name",64);
        $table->string("last_name",64);
        $table->string("grand_father_name",64);
        $table->string("graduation_year",4)->unique();
        $table->enum("gender",['0','1']);
        $table->unsignedSmallInteger('school_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger("province_id")->nullable();
        $table->foreign('school_id')->reference('id')->on('schools')- 
       >onDelete('set null');
        $table->foreign('province_id')->reference('id')->on('provinces')->onDelete('set null');
    });
}

    public function up()
            {
                Schema::table('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->unsignedBigInteger('province_id')->nullable();
                    $table->foreign('province_id')->reference('id')->on('provinces')
                 ->onDelete('set null');
                });
            }
```